# prove using the principle of mathematical induction any amounts could build by 4cent and 11cent stamps

Tags: discrete-mathematics

By using 'inductive step' to prove it:

some steps from textbook solution:(by I still do not get it)
11 = 4*3-1
11+1 = 4*3
4*8+1 = 32+1 = 11*3
how to prove P(k+1) is ture?

Comment: See [this](https://www.slader.com/discussion/question/a-determine-which-amounts-of-postage-can-be-formed-using-just-4-cent-and-11-cent-stamps-b-prove-your/#). Specifically, the section for strong mathematical induction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you mean any amount $\ge30$. Since $30=8+22,\,31=20+11,\,32=32+0,\,33=0+33$, we can add multiples of $4$ thereafter. The formal way to do this is to prove by weak induction that $4n-2$ to $4n+1$ inclusive are achievable for $n\ge8$.

Comment: your solution makes sense for me, but I think this is strong induction. Which is not the way I am looking for

Comment: @xyz666999 It's not strong. Let $P(n)$ denote "$4n-2$ to $4n+1$ inclusive are achievable". You can easily verify $P(8)$; you can easily verify $P(n)\implies P(n+1)$; therefore, you can easily verify $P(n)$ for all $nge8$.